# How can I access properties inherited from BaseChart in Google's flutter_chart library?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using [this](https://github.com/google/charts/tree/master/charts_flutter) charts library by Google.

I'm creating a new [LineChart](https://pub.dev/documentation/charts_common/latest/common/LineChart-class.html) like

```
chart = new charts.LineChart(
  series,
  animate: true,
  domainAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
    viewport: new charts.NumericExtents(3101.0, 3600.0)),
  behaviors: [
    new charts.PanBehavior(panningCompletedCallback: _onPanEnd),
  ],
);
```

And I want to be able to access the properties inherited from [BaseChart](https://pub.dev/documentation/charts_common/latest/common/BaseChart-class.html). The inheritance is like such: LineChart extends NumericCartesianChart extends CartesianChart extends BaseChart.

I **can** access the properties of CartesianChart without problem, but not the properties of BaseChart.

`print(chart.domainAxis.viewport);` outputs "flutter: Extent(3101.0, 3600.0)"

But 
`print(chart.chartHeight);` throws

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, state:
flutter: _MyHomePageState#4dfc6):
flutter: Class 'LineChart' has no instance getter 'chartHeight'.
flutter: Receiver: Instance of 'LineChart'
flutter: Tried calling: chartHeight
```

Super thank you to anyone who can help!!!

Answer (score 1):

This confused me for a little while - dart inheritance normally works properly and if it wasn't then a lot of stuff would have to have gone wrong!

But alas, the issue is that the 'charts_flutter' and 'charts_common' libraries are very similar, and both happen to include a 'BaseChart' and 'LineChart'. So you should be looking at the [flutter_charts' version of BaseChart](https://pub.dev/documentation/charts_flutter/latest/flutter/BaseChart-class.html) and [of LineChart](https://pub.dev/documentation/charts_flutter/latest/flutter/LineChart-class.html) instead.

Unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue that you can't access 'chartHeight' because that class doesn't have a chartHeight, but hopefully you'll be able to resolve your underlying problem in a different way now that you're reading the right documentation.

Comment: Okay I think this might be a heck of a start. Thanks! (and facepalm)

Now I can do  `chart_state = chart.createState(); base_chart = chart.createCommonChart(chart_state);` To get access to the properties I was talking about. But now `print(base_chart.chartHeight);` returns Null. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Uh I might be wrong as there isnct a huge amount of documentation around common_charts, I wouldn't expect it to work on flutter without quite a lot of work hooking it up, you should really be using the Flutter version of things (i.e. the LineChart) as widgets that size themselves within whatever their parents are. They use common charts under the hood and have already done all the plumbing to get them to work in flutter.